# output in BarChart with stacks is empty NaN

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a problem with the stacked barchart in dc.

I think it's a problem with the group, but I'm not sure.
Can someone please help me.. I'm working on this problem for days.
The BarChart sould show the date (date in this .csv is "daten_stand") on the x-Axis. And on the y-Axis, three Stacks. One for the column of the csv "faelle_covid_aktuell", on for "betten_frei" and on for "betten_belegt". Additionally I filtered all the data by die column "bundesland" (state);

Hier you can see the code and the csv...

```js
let barChartContainer1;

let barChart;


function drawbarChar() {

    barChart = new dc.BarChart("#" + barChartContainer1[0].id);

    d3.csv("../data/betten_BarChart.csv").then(function (data) {

        let filterData = data.filter(x => x.bundesland == "01");
        let newData = [];
        let i = 0;


       filterData.forEach(element => {
            let parts = element.daten_stand.split('-');
            let date = parts[2] + "." + parts[1] + "." +parts[0];
            newData.push([element.daten_stand, element.gemeindeschluessel, "betten_frei", element.betten_frei]);
            i++;
            newData.push([element.daten_stand, element.gemeindeschluessel, "betten_belegt", element.betten_belegt]);
            i++;
            newData.push([element.daten_stand, element.gemeindeschluessel, "faelle_covid_aktuell", element.faelle_covid_aktuell]);
            i++;
        });


        var myCrossfilter = crossfilter(newData),
            dim = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {

                return d;
            }),
            group = dim.group().reduce((p, d)=> {
                //p[d.gemeindeschluessel] = (p[d.gemeindeschluessel] || 0) + d.betten_frei;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) + d.faelle_covid_aktuell;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) + d.betten_frei;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) + d.betten_belegt;
                console.log(p)
                return p;

            }, function reduceRemove(p, d) {
               // p[d.gemeindeschluessel] = (p[d.gemeindeschluessel] || 0) - d.betten_frei;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) - d.faelle_covid_aktuell;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) - d.betten_frei;
                p[d] = (p[d] || 0) - d.betten_belegt;
                return p;

            }, () => ({}));

        function sel_stack (i) {
            return function (dataItem) {
                return dataItem.value[i];
            };
        }

        barChart
            .height(200)
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 21]))
            .brushOn(false)
            .clipPadding(10)

            .dimension(dim)
            .group(group, '1', sel_stack('1'))
            .renderLabel(true);

        barChart.legend(dc.legend());


        for(var j = 2; j<4; j++){
            barChart.stack(group, '' + j, sel_stack(j))
        }

        barChart.render();
    });

}




$(document).ready(function () {

 
    barChartContainer1 = $("#right-graph1");
    drawbarChar();



    $(window).resize(function () {

        drawbarChar();
  
    });
});
```

```css
bundesland,gemeindeschluessel,anzahl_meldebereiche,faelle_covid_aktuell,faelle_covid_aktuell_beatmet,anzahl_standorte,betten_frei,betten_belegt,daten_stand
01,01001,2,0,0,2,51,32,2020-06-07
01,01002,5,0,0,3,136,122,2020-06-07
01,01003,2,0,0,2,135,108,2020-06-07
01,01004,1,0,0,1,22,18,2020-06-07
01,01051,1,1,0,1,22,34,2020-06-07
01,01053,2,0,0,2,14,10,2020-06-07
01,01054,3,0,0,3,23,21,2020-06-07
01,01055,3,0,0,3,20,32,2020-06-07
01,01056,2,0,0,2,9,26,2020-06-07
01,01057,1,0,0,1,7,5,2020-06-07
01,01058,3,0,0,3,15,35,2020-06-07
01,01059,1,3,0,1,11,13,2020-06-07
01,01060,4,1,0,4,60,70,2020-06-07
01,01061,1,0,0,1,18,22,2020-06-07
01,01062,3,0,0,3,29,30,2020-06-07
02,02000,26,19,16,23,404,524,2020-06-07
03,03101,5,1,1,5,68,91,2020-06-07
03,03102,2,0,0,2,7,20,2020-06-07
03,03103,1,2,0,1,30,16,2020-06-07
03,03151,2,0,0,2,7,29,2020-06-07
03,03153,3,0,0,3,52,37,2020-06-07
03,03154,1,2,0,1,15,19,2020-06-07
03,03155,2,0,0,2,9,14,2020-06-07
03,03157,1,0,0,1,5,17,2020-06-07
03,03158,1,2,2,1,4,12,2020-06-07
03,03159,8,4,3,7,79,135,2020-06-07
03,03241,16,16,12,16,133,348,2020-06-07
03,03251,3,0,0,3,10,3,2020-06-07
03,03252,4,1,1,4,15,57,2020-06-07
03,03254,5,0,0,4,44,54,2020-06-07
03,03255,1,0,0,1,4,10,2020-06-07
03,03256,1,0,0,1,17,17,2020-06-07
03,03257,1,1,1,1,9,14,2020-06-07
03,03351,3,0,0,1,8,33,2020-06-07
03,03352,2,1,0,2,9,9,2020-06-07
03,03353,3,1,0,3,31,35,2020-06-07
03,03354,1,0,0,1,16,7,2020-06-07
03,03355,2,0,0,2,13,25,2020-06-07
03,03356,2,0,0,2,6,9,2020-06-07
03,03357,3,0,0,2,6,26,2020-06-07
03,03358,3,0,0,3,17,22,2020-06-07
03,03359,3,0,0,2,14,23,2020-06-07
03,03360,2,0,0,2,31,50,2020-06-07
03,03361,2,4,0,2,4,13,2020-06-07
03,03401,1,0,0,1,13,14,2020-06-07
03,03402,1,0,0,1,12,9,2020-06-07
03,03403,5,6,6,3,111,114,2020-06-07
03,03404,4,0,0,4,90,34,2020-06-07
03,03405,1,0,0,1,12,22,2020-06-07
03,03451,3,0,0,2,18,25,2020-06-07
03,03452,3,0,0,3,21,21,2020-06-07
03,03453,3,2,0,3,11,35,2020-06-07
03,03454,7,0,0,7,49,52,2020-06-07
03,03455,2,1,1,2,12,25,2020-06-07
03,03456,1,0,0,1,19,11,2020-06-07
03,03457,3,0,0,2,22,21,2020-06-07
03,03458,1,0,0,1,6,9,2020-06-07
03,03459,8,0,0,7,72,53,2020-06-07
03,03460,3,0,0,3,36,21,2020-06-07
03,03461,2,0,0,2,7,9,2020-06-07
03,03462,1,0,0,1,6,7,2020-06-07
04,04011,9,5,3,8,76,91,2020-06-07
04,04012,2,2,1,2,7,17,2020-06-07
05,05111,12,3,2,11,71,239,2020-06-07
05,05112,13,6,4,9,83,181,2020-06-07
05,05113,15,8,5,14,103,251,2020-06-07
05,05114,6,2,1,4,30,74,2020-06-07
05,05116,5,1,1,4,29,90,2020-06-07
05,05117,2,2,1,2,18,37,2020-06-07
05,05119,6,0,0,4,36,40,2020-06-07
05,05120,1,0,0,1,15,21,2020-06-07
05,05122,3,4,3,3,35,65,2020-06-07
05,05124,5,2,2,5,97,97,2020-06-07
05,05154,5,1,0,5,30,38,2020-06-07
05,05158,6,0,0,6,39,36,2020-06-07
05,05162,7,0,0,6,52,66,2020-06-07
05,05166,4,0,0,4,28,33,2020-06-07
05,05170,9,10,1,8,73,93,2020-06-07
05,05314,15,7,3,11,72,201,2020-06-07
05,05315,26,5,4,18,73,364,2020-06-07
05,05316,4,0,0,2,32,56,2020-06-07
05,05334,8,12,10,7,63,225,2020-06-07
05,05358,6,0,0,5,37,40,2020-06-07
05,05362,7,0,0,7,20,59,2020-06-07
05,05366,3,1,0,3,9,36,2020-06-07
05,05370,3,0,0,3,12,24,2020-06-07
05,05374,7,2,0,7,41,85,2020-06-07
05,05378,4,0,0,4,20,32,2020-06-07
05,05382,6,0,0,6,31,65,2020-06-07
05,05512,2,1,1,2,38,28,2020-06-07
05,05513,6,1,0,4,62,71,2020-06-07
05,05515,8,3,3,7,31,232,2020-06-07
05,05554,5,1,1,5,37,44,2020-06-07
05,05558,3,0,0,3,26,9,2020-06-07
05,05562,14,1,1,14,105,177,2020-06-07
05,05566,5,2,2,5,30,61,2020-06-07
05,05570,5,0,0,5,28,34,2020-06-07
05,05711,4,0,0,4,38,106,2020-06-07
05,05754,3,1,1,3,24,26,2020-06-07
05,05758,4,2,2,3,25,43,2020-06-07
05,05762,5,0,0,5,15,23,2020-06-07
05,05766,2,1,1,2,26,55,2020-06-07
05,05770,6,5,2,6,53,99,2020-06-07
05,05774,4,4,4,4,33,56,2020-06-07
05,05911,8,1,1,6,91,160,2020-06-07
05,05913,9,5,2,9,61,238,2020-06-07
05,05914,5,1,1,5,40,48,2020-06-07
05,05915,6,1,1,5,34,59,2020-06-07
05,05916,4,2,1,4,29,42,2020-06-07
05,05954,7,1,0,6,43,97,2020-06-07
05,05958,9,4,3,9,51,71,2020-06-07
05,05962,8,2,0,8,47,80,2020-06-07
05,05966,3,1,1,3,27,14,2020-06-07
05,05970,6,0,0,6,34,87,2020-06-07
05,05974,6,0,0,6,21,42,2020-06-07
05,05978,8,0,0,8,35,98,2020-06-07
06,06411,7,1,0,4,40,75,2020-06-07
06,06412,15,9,6,12,78,233,2020-06-07
06,06413,2,2,2,2,47,67,2020-06-07
06,06414,5,7,6,4,42,80,2020-06-07
06,06431,5,0,0,5,22,26,2020-06-07
06,06432,2,2,0,2,2,26,2020-06-07
06,06433,2,0,0,2,6,19,2020-06-07
06,06434,3,0,0,3,10,20,2020-06-07
06,06435,5,2,1,4,36,65,2020-06-07
06,06436,2,0,0,2,14,19,2020-06-07
06,06437,1,2,2,1,0,104,2020-06-07
06,06438,2,5,3,2,25,31,2020-06-07
06,06439,2,0,0,2,13,7,2020-06-07
06,06440,5,2,0,5,61,71,2020-06-07
06,06531,4,9,3,4,56,230,2020-06-07
06,06532,2,0,0,2,9,52,2020-06-07
06,06533,3,0,0,3,19,43,2020-06-07
06,06534,3,1,1,3,49,132,2020-06-07
06,06535,4,0,0,4,23,17,2020-06-07
06,06611,6,1,1,6,46,143,2020-06-07
06,06631,3,0,0,3,25,57,2020-06-07
06,06632,3,1,0,3,33,43,2020-06-07
06,06633,3,0,0,3,10,20,2020-06-07
06,06634,3,0,0,3,33,20,2020-06-07
06,06635,7,0,0,7,47,79,2020-06-07
06,06636,3,0,0,3,39,19,2020-06-07
07,07111,5,0,0,4,57,58,2020-06-07
07,07131,2,0,0,2,8,17,2020-06-07
07,07132,2,0,0,2,13,10,2020-06-07
07,07133,4,0,0,4,27,24,2020-06-07
07,07134,2,0,0,2,14,14,2020-06-07
07,07135,2,0,0,2,20,7,2020-06-07
07,07137,4,1,1,4,28,17,2020-06-07
07,07138,5,0,0,5,37,40,2020-06-07
07,07140,2,0,0,2,5,10,2020-06-07
07,07141,5,0,0,5,21,26,2020-06-07
07,07143,4,0,0,4,16,22,2020-06-07
07,07211,4,0,0,3,58,60,2020-06-07
07,07231,2,0,0,2,16,21,2020-06-07
07,07232,2,0,0,2,9,8,2020-06-07
07,07233,2,0,0,2,15,1,2020-06-07
07,07235,2,0,0,2,10,6,2020-06-07
07,07311,1,0,0,1,8,14,2020-06-07
07,07312,1,3,2,1,70,95,2020-06-07
07,07313,3,0,0,2,8,7,2020-06-07
07,07314,4,1,1,4,64,66,2020-06-07
07,07315,2,0,0,2,42,86,2020-06-07
07,07316,1,0,0,1,8,13,2020-06-07
07,07317,1,0,0,1,8,8,2020-06-07
07,07318,3,2,2,2,12,25,2020-06-07
07,07319,1,0,0,1,7,22,2020-06-07
07,07320,1,0,0,1,8,6,2020-06-07
07,07331,1,0,0,1,6,2,2020-06-07
07,07332,2,0,0,2,11,11,2020-06-07
07,07333,2,0,0,2,6,6,2020-06-07
07,07334,2,0,0,2,22,7,2020-06-07
07,07335,1,0,0,1,11,3,2020-06-07
07,07336,1,0,0,1,0,16,2020-06-07
07,07337,2,0,0,2,9,8,2020-06-07
07,07339,2,4,4,2,10,17,2020-06-07
07,07340,1,0,0,1,7,2,2020-06-07
08,08111,11,11,5,9,218,299,2020-06-07
08,08115,4,0,0,4,20,29,2020-06-07
08,08116,6,4,0,4,25,47,2020-06-07
08,08117,4,2,0,3,31,44,2020-06-07
08,08118,5,13,7,4,137,77,2020-06-07
08,08119,2,2,1,2,66,43,2020-06-07
08,08121,1,1,1,1,32,36,2020-06-07
08,08125,2,0,0,2,12,40,2020-06-07
08,08126,1,0,0,1,7,5,2020-06-07
08,08127,2,1,0,2,24,28,2020-06-07
08,08128,3,1,1,3,30,38,2020-06-07
08,08135,1,0,0,1,7,17,2020-06-07
08,08136,3,1,0,3,26,29,2020-06-07
08,08211,2,1,0,1,13,11,2020-06-07
08,08212,4,0,0,4,52,81,2020-06-07
08,08215,3,3,2,3,18,48,2020-06-07
08,08216,2,0,0,2,4,11,2020-06-07
08,08221,6,7,5,6,112,217,2020-06-07
08,08222,5,3,2,3,37,98,2020-06-07
08,08225,3,0,0,3,11,7,2020-06-07
08,08226,4,1,0,4,12,25,2020-06-07
08,08231,2,2,0,2,18,45,2020-06-07
08,08235,2,0,0,2,17,5,2020-06-07
08,08236,2,0,0,2,13,14,2020-06-07
08,08237,1,0,0,1,2,8,2020-06-07
08,08311,4,4,3,4,103,135,2020-06-07
08,08315,4,0,0,4,43,71,2020-06-07
08,08316,3,1,1,3,8,26,2020-06-07
08,08317,6,2,0,6,66,56,2020-06-07
08,08325,2,1,1,2,5,7,2020-06-07
08,08326,5,13,2,2,51,48,2020-06-07
08,08327,1,2,1,1,15,6,2020-06-07
08,08335,7,0,0,6,29,66,2020-06-07
08,08336,1,0,0,1,0,19,2020-06-07
08,08337,2,1,1,2,12,26,2020-06-07
08,08415,2,1,1,1,12,24,2020-06-07
08,08416,5,5,4,2,24,99,2020-06-07
08,08417,1,0,0,1,18,12,2020-06-07
08,08421,3,0,0,3,49,84,2020-06-07
08,08425,2,0,0,2,19,11,2020-06-07
08,08426,1,0,0,1,20,7,2020-06-07
08,08435,3,0,0,3,40,34,2020-06-07
08,08436,5,2,1,4,18,44,2020-06-07
08,08437,2,0,0,2,15,12,2020-06-07
09,09161,2,8,3,1,6,30,2020-06-07
09,09162,28,41,29,26,225,554,2020-06-07
09,09163,1,0,0,1,38,32,2020-06-07
09,09171,3,0,0,2,6,35,2020-06-07
09,09172,3,0,0,3,1,20,2020-06-07
09,09173,2,0,0,2,4,24,2020-06-07
09,09174,1,1,1,1,42,26,2020-06-07
09,09175,1,0,0,1,11,9,2020-06-07
09,09176,3,4,3,3,19,57,2020-06-07
09,09177,1,0,0,1,14,13,2020-06-07
09,09178,1,3,3,1,3,19,2020-06-07
09,09179,1,0,0,1,6,9,2020-06-07
09,09180,1,0,0,1,26,45,2020-06-07
09,09181,1,0,0,1,3,7,2020-06-07
09,09182,1,0,0,1,22,8,2020-06-07
09,09183,1,0,0,1,11,15,2020-06-07
09,09184,2,0,0,2,8,9,2020-06-07
09,09185,3,1,1,2,9,8,2020-06-07
09,09186,1,0,0,1,4,9,2020-06-07
09,09187,5,6,2,5,27,41,2020-06-07
09,09188,5,3,3,5,44,44,2020-06-07
09,09189,3,3,3,2,18,44,2020-06-07
09,09190,3,0,0,3,23,20,2020-06-07
09,09261,5,1,1,3,12,55,2020-06-07
09,09262,2,0,0,2,16,13,2020-06-07
09,09263,1,0,0,1,30,13,2020-06-07
09,09271,2,0,0,2,4,31,2020-06-07
09,09272,2,0,0,2,10,12,2020-06-07
09,09273,3,0,0,3,20,12,2020-06-07
09,09274,1,0,0,1,4,6,2020-06-07
09,09275,1,2,2,1,4,16,2020-06-07
09,09276,2,0,0,2,14,11,2020-06-07
09,09277,1,1,1,1,22,13,2020-06-07
09,09278,2,0,0,2,17,7,2020-06-07
09,09279,2,1,0,2,7,19,2020-06-07
09,09361,1,2,1,1,18,20,2020-06-07
09,09362,3,14,10,3,102,163,2020-06-07
09,09363,1,3,2,1,24,49,2020-06-07
09,09371,1,1,1,1,11,3,2020-06-07
09,09372,1,0,0,1,8,14,2020-06-07
09,09373,1,0,0,1,7,23,2020-06-07
09,09375,2,1,0,2,4,10,2020-06-07
09,09376,4,0,0,4,31,15,2020-06-07
09,09377,1,0,0,1,2,10,2020-06-07
09,09461,4,1,0,1,27,31,2020-06-07
09,09462,5,0,0,2,15,44,2020-06-07
09,09463,1,2,1,1,10,26,2020-06-07
09,09464,1,0,0,1,15,27,2020-06-07
09,09471,2,0,0,2,10,7,2020-06-07
09,09472,1,0,0,1,8,1,2020-06-07
09,09474,2,0,0,2,13,10,2020-06-07
09,09475,2,0,0,2,3,14,2020-06-07
09,09476,1,0,0,1,1,14,2020-06-07
09,09477,1,0,0,1,11,27,2020-06-07
09,09478,2,3,0,2,8,22,2020-06-07
09,09479,2,0,0,2,13,7,2020-06-07
09,09561,2,1,1,2,9,14,2020-06-07
09,09562,3,5,1,3,35,128,2020-06-07
09,09563,2,1,0,2,19,34,2020-06-07
09,09564,8,1,0,6,88,152,2020-06-07
09,09565,1,1,0,1,2,5,2020-06-07
09,09571,2,0,0,2,8,9,2020-06-07
09,09572,1,0,0,1,1,5,2020-06-07
09,09574,3,0,0,3,10,14,2020-06-07
09,09575,3,0,0,2,20,51,2020-06-07
09,09576,1,0,0,1,4,7,2020-06-07
09,09577,2,0,0,2,6,10,2020-06-07
09,09661,2,1,1,1,10,43,2020-06-07
09,09662,2,1,1,2,6,39,2020-06-07
09,09663,3,4,4,3,50,109,2020-06-07
09,09671,1,0,0,1,5,3,2020-06-07
09,09672,4,0,0,4,11,42,2020-06-07
09,09673,1,0,0,1,40,122,2020-06-07
09,09674,2,0,0,2,12,4,2020-06-07
09,09675,1,0,0,1,0,10,2020-06-07
09,09676,1,0,0,1,5,9,2020-06-07
09,09677,1,0,0,1,2,7,2020-06-07
09,09678,2,0,0,2,5,1,2020-06-07
09,09679,1,0,0,1,8,4,2020-06-07
09,09761,3,0,0,2,48,100,2020-06-07
09,09762,1,0,0,1,18,13,2020-06-07
09,09763,1,0,0,1,7,24,2020-06-07
09,09764,1,0,0,1,15,19,2020-06-07
09,09771,2,2,0,2,10,16,2020-06-07
09,09772,2,0,0,2,9,9,2020-06-07
09,09773,2,0,0,2,10,14,2020-06-07
09,09774,4,0,0,4,21,50,2020-06-07
09,09775,2,2,0,2,11,12,2020-06-07
09,09776,2,0,0,2,13,1,2020-06-07
09,09777,2,0,0,2,8,12,2020-06-07
09,09778,2,0,0,2,11,9,2020-06-07
09,09779,3,0,0,3,21,12,2020-06-07
09,09780,1,0,0,1,11,12,2020-06-07
10,10041,7,2,1,7,87,139,2020-06-07
10,10042,2,0,0,2,18,7,2020-06-07
10,10043,3,0,0,3,18,31,2020-06-07
10,10044,4,2,1,3,36,35,2020-06-07
10,10045,2,1,0,2,109,164,2020-06-07
10,10046,1,2,1,1,5,11,2020-06-07
11,11000,59,59,43,42,362,1048,2020-06-07
12,12051,3,1,0,3,10,45,2020-06-07
12,12052,2,0,0,2,52,51,2020-06-07
12,12053,1,0,0,1,12,29,2020-06-07
12,12054,4,0,0,4,26,57,2020-06-07
12,12060,2,1,0,2,55,57,2020-06-07
12,12061,5,0,0,5,18,54,2020-06-07
12,12062,3,0,0,3,23,26,2020-06-07
12,12063,4,0,0,2,16,13,2020-06-07
12,12064,3,0,0,3,13,23,2020-06-07
12,12065,5,0,0,5,39,20,2020-06-07
12,12066,1,3,0,1,23,22,2020-06-07
12,12067,4,0,0,4,88,64,2020-06-07
12,12068,3,0,0,3,23,23,2020-06-07
12,12069,3,0,0,3,43,58,2020-06-07
12,12070,2,0,0,2,18,7,2020-06-07
12,12071,3,0,0,3,10,13,2020-06-07
12,12072,2,0,0,2,12,10,2020-06-07
12,12073,4,0,0,4,14,27,2020-06-07
13,13003,2,1,1,2,39,80,2020-06-07
13,13004,1,0,0,1,7,47,2020-06-07
13,13071,5,1,0,5,37,54,2020-06-07
13,13072,6,0,0,4,36,30,2020-06-07
13,13073,4,0,0,4,24,47,2020-06-07
13,13074,2,0,0,2,10,35,2020-06-07
13,13075,7,0,0,7,69,159,2020-06-07
13,13076,7,0,0,7,55,142,2020-06-07
14,14511,3,0,0,3,24,148,2020-06-07
14,14521,6,0,0,6,31,54,2020-06-07
14,14522,5,0,0,5,35,38,2020-06-07
14,14523,4,0,0,4,46,46,2020-06-07
14,14524,6,1,0,5,37,82,2020-06-07
14,14612,12,0,0,6,67,218,2020-06-07
14,14625,6,3,3,5,21,43,2020-06-07
14,14626,6,0,0,6,33,33,2020-06-07
14,14627,5,0,0,5,47,49,2020-06-07
14,14628,6,26,6,6,60,66,2020-06-07
14,14713,9,0,0,7,166,263,2020-06-07
14,14729,3,0,0,3,24,29,2020-06-07
14,14730,8,0,0,8,36,44,2020-06-07
15,15001,2,0,0,2,20,28,2020-06-07
15,15002,6,4,3,5,93,220,2020-06-07
15,15003,7,0,0,5,52,176,2020-06-07
15,15081,2,0,0,2,8,12,2020-06-07
15,15082,3,0,0,3,26,26,2020-06-07
15,15083,2,0,0,2,25,13,2020-06-07
15,15084,3,0,0,3,39,18,2020-06-07
15,15085,4,0,0,4,22,33,2020-06-07
15,15086,2,5,4,2,13,17,2020-06-07
15,15087,3,0,0,3,25,11,2020-06-07
15,15088,2,0,0,2,11,12,2020-06-07
15,15089,4,0,0,4,25,48,2020-06-07
15,15090,2,0,0,2,32,26,2020-06-07
15,15091,2,0,0,2,38,25,2020-06-07
16,16051,2,3,0,2,30,66,2020-06-07
16,16052,1,3,1,1,10,36,2020-06-07
16,16053,1,0,0,1,18,97,2020-06-07
16,16054,1,1,1,1,11,11,2020-06-07
16,16055,1,0,0,1,5,11,2020-06-07
16,16056,1,0,0,1,21,23,2020-06-07
16,16061,3,1,1,3,14,16,2020-06-07
16,16062,3,3,0,3,45,36,2020-06-07
16,16063,3,0,0,3,21,66,2020-06-07
16,16064,3,1,1,3,47,26,2020-06-07
16,16065,1,0,0,1,4,7,2020-06-07
16,16066,2,0,0,2,11,37,2020-06-07
16,16067,2,0,0,2,25,16,2020-06-07
16,16068,1,0,0,1,6,8,2020-06-07
16,16069,1,0,0,1,5,3,2020-06-07
16,16070,2,0,0,2,12,6,2020-06-07
16,16071,3,0,0,3,57,69,2020-06-07
16,16072,1,0,0,1,4,4,2020-06-07
16,16073,1,0,0,1,9,13,2020-06-07
16,16074,1,0,0,1,12,4,2020-06-07
16,16075,1,0,0,1,0,0,2020-06-07
16,16076,1,2,2,1,6,11,2020-06-07
16,16077,2,0,0,1,30,30,2020-06-07
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Philipp Fruh">
    <meta name="generator" content="">
    <title>Angewandtes Projekt: Visualisierung SS20</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-aAr2Zpq8MZ+YA/D6JtRD3xtrwpEz2IqOS+pWD/7XKIw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="./stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white border shadow rounded mt-2">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Content -->
    <!-- Top Row -->
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-md-12 p-2 px-3">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <div id="top-graph"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bottom Row -->
    <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <!-- Left -->
        <div class="col-md-4 p-2 pl-3">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Auslastung ÖPNV am 19.05.2020</h5>
                    <div id="left-graph"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Middle -->
        <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Kartenausschnitt Umkreis Uniklinikum Mannheim</h5>
                    <div id="middle-graph"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Right -->
        <div class="col-md-4 p-2 pr-3">
            <div class="card shadow h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Auslastung der Krankenhäuser Mannheim</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-title">Belegung der Intensivbetten im Kreis Mannheim</h6>
                    <div id="right-graph1"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-title">Universitätsklinikum</h6>
                    <div id="right-graph2"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-title">Diakonissenkrankenhaus</h6>
                    <div id="right-graph3"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-title">Theresienkrankenhaus</h6>
                    <div id="right-graph4"></div>
                    <div id="right-graph"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-OFRAJNoaD8L3Br5lglV7VyLRf0itmoBzWUoM+Sji4/8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha256-Xb6SSzhH3wEPC4Vy3W70Lqh9Y3Du/3KxPqI2JHQSpTw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.0.3/dc.min.js" integrity="sha256-nnWFwZ3i2j5HWFnLM8oZrkabWG1Pn080eVXL6MvLsH4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js" integrity="sha256-T9tvV3x+/vCnCoFciKNZwbaJ46q9lh6iZjD0ZjD95lE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/heatmap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to say that "gemeindeschluessel" is the numer of the city and "bundesland" the number of the state.

Comment: I can see that you have tried a lot of things here. This has strange things like returning the whole row in the dimension key function, some indecision about whether to have rows be arrays or objects with fields, indexing the object in the reduce functions with the entire row (`d`). I'm not sure if you started with one approach and then went in a different direction, or are copying and pasting from many examples which work differently. Maybe take a closer look at how the [stacked bar example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) works, that I think you started from?

Comment: I tried much thinks but I didn't really understood the group() function. I thought someone can tell me the right using of group() in this context.

Comment: Maybe this example is easier to understand for your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151972/dc-js-stacked-barchart-cant-display There's a lot of dc.js examples, if you search for `[dc.js] stacked` in the search bar at the top of the page you'll find many answers on this. Sorry I don't have time for this right now.

Comment: ok, I think I got it now.. but do anybody know, how I can put the date on my x-Axis?

Comment: Search for `tickFormat`